# Your LinkedIn Network Will Be Back Soon error while trying integrate LinkedIn API in PHP

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

I have been trying to integrate LinkedIn API in my PHP application to get the latest posts. I have created an app and configured the necessary settings and tried to access LinkedIn API. But I am getting "Your LinkedIn Network Will Be Back Soon" error and my authentication is not resolving. It would be great if I could get more insight into the issue like if is it something missing from the code or if anything else needs to be configured in the app settings.

I tried with normal PHP curl and also using an PHP library but got the same result.

I have raised a support request to sort out the issue as mentioned in one of the Stack Overflow comments and they have replied to raise the query in Stack Overflow so that their LinkedIn engineers will see them.

Answer (score 0):

Your LinkedIn network will be back soon and you have to wait until there will be response from LinkedIn server. There is no alternate way as of today 2023-12-26, only have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your LinkedIn MFA through LinkedIn mobile app. Login again LinkedIn using browser. Should be resolved.

Try enable MFA again later.